# Is it logical to say that $ 2\over 0$ $\ne$ $ 2\over 0$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, indeterminate-forms

As I was doing a math exercice, I came across a question which I decided to prove by contrapositive. That required me to show that $ f(4-x)$ $\ne$ $f(x)$ - but in both cases the result was $ 2\over 0$.
So my question is; is it correct to say that $ f(4-x)$ $\ne$ $f(x)$ since $ 2\over 0$ is undefined?

Comment: "but in both cases the result was 2/0" I assume you tried to solve $f(x) = f(4-x)$ and you perhaps showed that if so then $0x = 2$ for example. The result of this step would then be there is no solution, not that the solution is $2/0$. Maybe its best to add that exercise as context to the question.

Comment: Let $f(x)$ = $2 \over |x-2| -1$ 
1)Determine the domain of $f(x)$ 
2) Prove that for all x $\epsilon$ $\mathbb{R^-}$, $0\le f(x)\le 2$ 
3) Prove that for all x $\epsilon$ Domain of $f$, $(4-x)$ $\epsilon$ Domain of $f$ and $f(4-x) = f(x)$

Comment: This is the exercice. I encountered the problem during the last question.

Comment: And how did you get $2/0$ out of this? It seems to me that that would give $2\not= 2$ or similar which is just a normal contradiction. In any case a direct proof is much better here: to simply insert $(4-x)$ into $f$ and do simple manipulation to show that it equals $f(x)$.

Comment: Instead of \epsilon use \in, as for the exercise have you found the domain of $f$ if so when did you get to divide by zero?

Comment: Since I decided to go with a contrapositive, I picked an x which is not in the domain; which was 1. Both $f(1)$ and $f(5-1) $ result in $2/0$ - but I guess my reasoning was false.

Comment: Do you have any reason to believe it could mean something? Statements only have meaning when we assign meaning to them.

Comment: Ah ok, now I see. The contrapositive of “if $x$ is in the domain then $f(x) = f(4-x)$” is “if $f(x) \not= f(4-x)$ then $x$ is not in the domain”. To prove this you cannot just pick a number not in the domain and show that $f(x) \not= f(4-x)$, you have to show that whenever $f(x) \not= f(4-x)$ then $x$ cannot be in the domain. So you can see that doing it via contrapositive doesn't make it any easier than going the direct route.

Comment: Yes, that's what I was trying to do. But is it right or wrong? And how would you do it directly?

Comment: I see that doing it directly would mean that all real values of x is a solution to $f(x)$ = $f(4-x)$ which pretty much answers the question.

Comment: Its wrong. If you struggle to see why consider a simpler example: the contrapositive of “If you are old then you are rich” is “If you are poor then you must be young”. The way you tried to prove this was to check all the young people and verify that they are indeed poor. This does not rule out that there are any poor old people - you didn’t check that. What you should have done was instead to check all the poor people and verify that none of them was old. Here “being old” = “$x$ is in the domain” and “being rich” = “$f(x) = f(4-x)$”.

Comment: Direct is just to verify that the expression for $f(x)$ equals the expression for $f(4-x)$. Write them both down and compare them (and you might need do some simple manipulations like using $|-A| = |A|$ to get there).

Comment: Yes, I did check the direct proof and it's much simpler. Now, I clearly see the flaw in my reasoning and honestly it was a stupid mistake. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming the mathematics you are studying keeps division by zero undefined. So then a statement like $2\over0$ $\neq$ $2\over0$ has no meaning as some of symbols involved have no meaning (depending on the mathematics you are dealing with). More context about the problem might be helpful.